# How to pass database object to ApolloServer

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to understand how to pass my mongoose model to resolvers. So far I know 3 ways:

- Define model globally (this is of course ugly)
- Pass model in `context` parameter of the `ApolloServer` constructor. Documentation states that whatever is shared across resolvers, can be passed in context. Models belong to that category.
- Pass model in `dataSource` parameter to `ApolloServer` constructor. Extend `apollo-datasource` and add convenience functions. Looks like this is also good candidate.

So which way is proper for passing data model to resolvers?

Comment: Both context and data source seems fine. If I understand data sources correctly they are an abstraction layer, I don't really see the value in wrapping your mongoose in it though. We use data loaders to cache and batch requests. For each request we instantiate data loaders and attach them to the context. This has worked pretty well for us.

Comment: @Herku it would be very helpful to see your answer with some sample regarding dataloaders caching/batching through context.